# how to run project in iphone mobile

Tags: iphone

hi i am new to iPhone application development. i developed a simple project on xcode now i check it in mobile. how can i done this ,means need to create exe file or any thing else
pls help me

Answer (score 2):

The first step is to join the iPhone development program. Once you that and follow the instructions of createing a developer certificate you can run your code on a physical device. If you're using the latest version if Xcode just connect your device - choose device in the build settings and build & run. It will install the app on your device and run it.

[iPhone developer program](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/index.action)

[Obtaining your iPhone Development Certificate](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/manage/certificates/team/howto.action) - Requires login to apple dev center

Comment: Remember to create a certificate for EACH device you want to test your app on

Comment: Actually no need to create a certificate or provisioning pre app or device, just need to add the device.

Beginning with xcode 3.2 you don't need to create a provisioning profile for each app and device you code in order to test it. xcode now includes a team provisioning profile that automatically includes all the devices registered in your account.